# My ternary code is not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, conditional-operator

what I convert to ternary:

```
arr= ["A","T","T","G","C"]
 const result = arr.reduce((acc, current)=>{
  if(current === "A"){
    acc+= "T"
  } else if(current === "T"){
    acc+= "A"
  } else if(current === "G"){
    acc+=  "C"
  } else if( current === "C"){
    acc+=  "G"
  }
  return acc
},"")

console.log(result)
```

This is how I convert it in ternary but it's not working, its give undefined:

```
const result = arr.reduce((acc, current)=>{
 current === "A"? acc+= "T"
 : current === "T"? acc+="A"
 : current === "G"? acc+="C"
 : current === "C"? acc+= "G"
                : acc
 
},"")
```

Comment: Arrow functions that use `{}` do not implicitly return.  `() => 3` would implicitly return 3.  `() => { 3 }` would not.  `{}` require you to use a `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning the result in your ternary reduce example.

You should do:

```
const res2 = arr.reduce((acc, current)=>{
 return current === "A"? acc+= "T"
 : current === "T"? acc+="A"
 : current === "G"? acc+="C"
 : current === "C"? acc+= "G"
                : acc
 
},"")
```

You could also drop the brackets and just do:

```
const res2 = arr.reduce(
  (acc, current)=>
    current === "A"? acc+= "T"
     : current === "T"? acc+="A"
     : current === "G"? acc+="C"
     : current === "C"? acc+= "G"
     : acc
 ,"")
```